# How to start with biaxial tensile strain and compressive strain in TMDCs using VASP?

Tags: vasp

Good morning!

I would like to test the biaxial tensile strain and compressive strain in a hexagonal material from the TMDC group (for example HfS2).
How to get it into VASP?
What are the best ways to optimize geometry?
Can I fall into some traps?

```
HfS2
1.0
 3.6389749050         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
-1.8194881106         3.1514448821         0.0000000000
 0.0000000000         0.0000000000        22.8899211884
 Hf    S
  1    2
 Direct
 0.000000000         0.000000000         0.500000000
 0.666666985         0.333332986         0.563098013
 0.333332986         0.666666985         0.436901987
```

Could you help me with this as example?

Comment: +1. Thank you Milosz for contributing your very nice question here. Could you please put the contents of your screenshot, into a `code` block instead of doing a screenshot? What you have done is not the right way to present your question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get it into VASP?

**The key point is to generate different POSCAR files.** Once you prepare input files, you can perform the calculation with VASP. I will assume you are considering [monolayer T-phase HfS2](https://materialsweb.org/twodmaterials/result/mw-290) and show how to generate compressive and tensile structures.

- Initial structure:[HfS2.vasp]

  ```
  HfS2
  1.0
   3.6389749050         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
  -1.8194881106         3.1514448821         0.0000000000
   0.0000000000         0.0000000000        22.8899211884
   Hf    S
    1    2
   Direct
   0.000000000         0.000000000         0.500000000
   0.666666985         0.333332986         0.563098013
   0.333332986         0.666666985         0.436901987
  ```
- Then you can apply the biaxial strain for this structure by changing the length of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ at the same time. In detail, you can do this with the following python script:

  ```
  import numpy as np

  def bistrain(path1,path2,strain):

    with open(path1,'r') as f1:
      lines = f1.readlines()

    lattice = np.zeros((3,3))
    for i in range(3):lattice[i,:]=list(map(float,lines[2+i].strip().split()))

    lattice[0:2,0:2]=lattice[0:2,0:2]*strain

    with open(path2+'strain_'+str(strain)+'.vasp','w') as f2:
      f2.write(lines[0])
      f2.write(lines[1])

    for j in range(3):f2.write("%20.16f  %20.16f  %20.16f" %(lattice[j,0],lattice[j,1],lattice[j,2])+'\n')


    for k in range(5,len(lines)):f2.write(lines[k])

    #==================================================================
    path1='./HfS2.vasp'
    path2='./'
    #strain=0.99   ## compressive strain
    strain=1.01    ## tensile strain 
    bistrain(path1,path2,strain)
  ```

> What are the best ways to optimize geometry?

When the POSCAR is prepared, you can relax the structure [referring to this answer.](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/geometry-optimization-for-n-layers-in-vasp/2023#2023)

> Can I fall into some traps?

For the initial structure, you should use fractional coordinates rather than Cartesian coordinates.

May it hopes.

Comment: can you please explain the script. its not generating any output

Comment: It looks like this was intended to be a comment on one of the answers. When you have sufficient rep, you can add a comment. For now, I'm moving this onto Jack's answer. If you don't know Python well, you might not realize his script is a function that you need to explicitly call, rather than just running the file containing it.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to jack's answer.  This is easily implemented in [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/).

Here is the same example which creates biaxial strain POSCARs from -5% to 5% strain in 1% increments.

```
from ase.io import read
from os import makedirs
import numpy as np

for strain in np.arange(0.95, 1.05, 0.01):
    atoms = read("POSCAR")
    atoms.cell[0:2, 0:2] *= strain
    atoms.positions[:, 0:2] *= strain
    makedirs("biaxial_{}".format(strain))
    atoms.write("biaxial_{}/POSCAR".format(strain))
```